# Reducing variability in body composition measurements

Tags: measurements

I have a Nokia Body+ scale that I use to regularly measure myself.  While weight tracking has been working as expected, I see some pretty big swings in body composition.  Below is a graph of one month's muscle mass measurements, where muscle mass has varied by about 15 points in a month and about 7 in a short series of measurements.

[image: Graph of one month's muscle mass measurements]

Up to this point, I'd been content to just look at the long term trend and let the errors average out, but I'm getting to the point where accuracy matters.  I've been trying to stay consistent in when I measure and what I'm wearing, but are there other things I could do to improve the measurement?  (For example, washing and/or drying my feet off ahead of time?)  Or is it that there's an inherent imprecision in this or all BIA scales and I should be looking at different measurement equipment?